# ElasticSearch - combining ( as a character and * as regexp

Tags: regex, entity-framework, elasticsearch, brackets

I am using Elastic Search in my Java server and I have an entity that has the data aaa(bbbccc). For some reason, when I use ( and * together I cannot find the entity (* should be search for any character and ( is a real character that appears in my data):

These searches find the entity:

```
aaa*
aaa(bbbccc)
aaa(
(bbbccc)
aaa(bbb
bbb*
*ccc
*bbbccc*
```

These searches does not find the entity:

```
*(bbb
*(bbbccc)
aaa(bbb*
```

What is the reason? What should I do so all searches I wrote above will find my entity?

Answer (score 0):

This might help. From the documentation for [query dsl](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters).

**reserved characters**

If you need to use any of the characters which function as operators in your query itself (and not as operators), then you should escape them with a leading backslash. For instance, to search for `(1+1)=2`, you would need to write your query as `\(1\+1\)=2`.

The reserved characters are: `+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /`